# Как сделать подсказку для поля setCustomValidity?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть форма регистрации, она не использует html тэг form, а работает исключительно на ajax запросах. Мне нужно сделать подсказки с выводом ошибок для поля, что-то новое придумывать не хочу. Но setCustomValidity не работает для меня, как исправить?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".input_form_input").focusout(function () {
        th = $(this).attr("id");
        val = $(this).val();
        if (th != "RpassRegister") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Register',
                data: {"type": "correct", "input": th, "data": val},
                success: function (data) {
                    if(val != "") {
                        if (data == "") {
                            $('#' + th).css("border-color", "#44f124");
                        } else {
                            $('#' + th).css("border-color", "red");
                            //$('#' + th).setCustomValidity(data); Тут ошибка
                        }
                    }
                },
            });
        } else {
            val1 = $("#passRegister").val();
            val2 = $("#RpassRegister").val();
            if(val1 != "") {
                if (val1 == val2) {
                    $("#RpassRegister").css("border-color", "#44f124");
                } else {
                    $("#RpassRegister").css("border-color", "red");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выводит?

Comment: 16:11:05.841 main.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setCustomValidity is not a function...Но она должна быть...

Comment: Какой JQuery используете, полностью название файла?

Comment: $('#' + th)[0].setCustomValidity(data);

Comment: версия jq 3.4.1

Comment: @Konst, правильно сказал, не успел)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `setCustomValidity` принадлежит `DOM`, что означает что такого метода в JQuery нет. Вам нужно получить объект JQuery и выбрать у него индекс `[0]`, чтобы использовать DOM элемент. Код будет таким:

```
$('#' + th)[0].setCustomValidity(data);
```

Comment: Это не выдает ошибку, но и отображения подсказки нет( мой код $('#emailRegister')[0].setCustomValidity("sssss"); ) поле <input class="input_form_input" id="emailRegister" type="email" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" spellcheck="false" style="border-color: red;">

Comment: Что вводите в поле?

Comment: email...который уже есть в базе. Запрос возвращает текст, что email занят

Comment: Через `consol.log(data)` посмотрите что приходит в ответ, и вообще есть ли что-то в `data`.

Comment: Почему-то работает когда использую в связке $('#' + th)[0].setCustomValidity(data);
                            $('#' + th)[0].reportValidity(data);

Comment: Именно, потому что вы вначале установили `setCustomValidity(data)`, а потом уже показываете `reportValidity(data)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#' + th)[0].setCustomValidity(data);
```

потому что метод HTMLSelectElement: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity

ПРИМЕР (подсказка на поле ввода в **форме**):

```
<form>
<input id="id1" type="text" required/>
<button onclick="$('#id1')[0].setCustomValidity('test error');">OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Это не выдает ошибку, но и отображения подсказки нет( мой код $('#emailRegister')[0].setCustomValidity("sssss"); ) поле <input class="input_form_input" id="emailRegister" type="email" autocomplete="off" maxlength="100" spellcheck="false" style="border-color: red;">